# How do I open .vb file path in Visual Studio (2013)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using the asp.net web forms and whenever I want to edit the MyWebPage.aspx.vb file to add something in the Page_Load subroutine, I have to add a temporary asp button or something like that and double click it. Is there a shortcut to open it??

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the buttons at the top of the Solution Explorer pane, one of them is "Show all files". Click that, and you will be able to expand MyWebPage.aspx to show the MyWebPage.aspx.vb file.

Alternatively, you can use "View" menu -> "Code" if you have MyWebPage.aspx showing in the designer.